# Автоматизация работы в нескольких браузерах по шаблону

Tags: авторизация, браузер, кроссбраузерность

у меня есть работа и я хотел бы автоматизировать ее.
Суть заключается в том, что я занимаюсь рекламой и я работаю в 8 браузерах одновременно, прикреплю фото для понимания.
Другими словами у меня открыто 8 браузеров по 1 вкладке и я делаю публикации по шаблону, а именно:

1. у меня есть фото и описание к нему
2. я копирую фото и описание и вставляю его в поле
3. выбираю время, через сколько будет удалена публикация
4. выбираю дату и время публикации( 2 фото )

Я хотел бы попытается автоматизировать этот процесс путем ввода данных во внешнюю какую-то среду дабы программа как-то сама выполняла по сути шаблонные действия.

Вопрос. Реально ли это сделать? По сути мне нужна имитация нажатия на кнопки и возможно с кое-какой логикой.

Знаю так же что есть отдельные приложения для гугл хрома, которые дают возможность выполнять сценарии, но это нужно для каждого браузера отдельно. В моем же случае нужно что бы я 1 раз выбрал картинку и текст, возможно еще какие-то настройки для выбора времени публикации и оно по шаблону выполнилось в каждом браузере.

Знаю что есть такие расширения по типу Automa. Но это для каждого браузера отдельно нужно тыкать.

Дико извиняюсь за возможно столь глупое описание моей задачи.

Если это возможно сделать при помощи какого-то языка программирования на плюс минус несложном уровне то готов его изучить и самому попытаться реализовать работу программы. Если же так можно то подскажите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.